# Too many math alphabets used in version normal when using 4 packages only

Tags: siunitx, debugging, newtxmath, bm

This one is very strange. After much struggle, I narrowed it down to some combination of 4 packages.  When I **comment any one of these 4 packages**, the error goes away.

MWE

```
\documentclass[12pt,notitlepage]{article}

\usepackage{newtxmath}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{esvect}

\begin{document} %equation is below is auto-generated by Maple 18.02
\[
 \left\{ y \left( x \right) =\int \!{\frac {1}{\sqrt {{\it a4}\,{x}^{4
}+{\it a3}\,{x}^{3}+{\it a2}\,{x}^{2}+{\it a1}\,x+{\it a0}}}}\,{\rm d}
x+{\it \_C1} \right\} 
\]

\end{document}
```

and now

```
pdflatex
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.15 (TeX Live 2014) (preloaded 
format=pdflatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
....
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/newtx/untxsyc.fd)
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/esvect/uesvect.fd)
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tex-gyre/t1qhv.fd)
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/newtx/t1ntxtt.fd)

! LaTeX Error: Too many math alphabets used in version normal.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.12 ...}+{\it a2}\,{x}^{2}+{\it a1}\,x+{\it a0}}}
                                                  }\,{\rm d}
?
```

Now, I can understand when including one package causes an error. But why when including these 4 seemingly completely unrelated package causes the error? What can  possibly package `bm` has to do with `siunitx`? and `newtxmath` has to do with `esvect`? This all seems so random to me.

This also happens on windows with Miktex:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: that's expected (and documented in the bm package documentation)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You just need to give `bm` a hint you are using a lot of alphabets:

```
\documentclass[12pt,notitlepage]{article}

\usepackage{newtxmath}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\newcommand\bmmax{2}
\usepackage{bm}

\usepackage{esvect}

\begin{document} %equation is below is auto-generated by Maple 18.02
\[
 \left\{ y \left( x \right) =\int \!{\frac {1}{\sqrt {{\it a4}\,{x}^{4
}+{\it a3}\,{x}^{3}+{\it a2}\,{x}^{2}+{\it a1}\,x+{\it a0}}}}\,{\rm d}
x+{\it \_C1} \right\} 
\]

\end{document}
```

Comment: It is worth pointing out that there is a good explanation of what is happening on the [UK List of
TeX Frequently Asked Questions](http://www.tex.ac.uk/FAQ-manymathalph.html).

Answer (score 4):

TeX has capacity for only 16 maths alphabets. If you load packages which define different maths alphabets, then the effect is cumulative. So while any 3 of those packages may take the total to fewer than 16, all 4 may take it over 16 and TeX will complain because it cannot handle the 17th one you try to define.

If you only need some alphabets from those packages, you can take code from the packages for just the bits you need, potentially bringing the total back under 16 without giving up anything you want to use.

For this particular equation, the following works:

```
\documentclass[12pt,notitlepage]{article}

\usepackage{newtxmath}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{esvect}

\begin{document} %equation is below is auto-generated by Maple 18.02

\[
\left\{ y \left( x \right) =\int \!{\frac {1}{\sqrt {a4\,{x}^{4
      }+a3\,{x}^{3}+a2\,{x}^{2}+a1\,x+a0}}}\,{\mathrm{d}}
x+\_C1 \right\}
\]

\end{document}
```

But, of course, the numbers are no longer italicised in this case.

Comment: thanks for the explanation of cause of error. I can't edit the equations, since these are auto-generated each time I run the program. Instead, I will remove one of the packages in this case. I am not sure I understand why this error show up in this file only, and not in any other file, since I use those 4 package in my common include file and never saw this error. I assume Maple code `{\it a1}` is then generating new math alphabet? In this case, Maple should not be doing this.

Comment: @Nasser If Maple generates `{\it a1}` then its converter is irremediably obsolete. If it used `\mathit` then something could be done for the problem. I'm not sure why you load `esvect` along with `newtxmath`.

Answer (score 3):

Just for fun, assuming that your Maple converter always uses

```
{\it ...}
```

which seems the case, here's a way to avoid the problem *for this equation*:

```
\documentclass[12pt,notitlepage]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{newtxmath}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{esvect}

\let\it\relax
\DeclareRobustCommand\it{%
  \ifmmode
    \expandafter\mmit
  \else
    \normalfont\itshape
  \fi
}
\def\mmit{%
  \egroup % end the started group
  \iftrue\expandafter\text\expandafter{\expandafter\itshape\else}\fi
}

\begin{document} %equation is below is auto-generated by Maple 18.02
\[
 \left\{ y \left( x \right) =\int \!{\frac {1}{\sqrt {{\it a4}\,{x}^{4
}+{\it a3}\,{x}^{3}+{\it a2}\,{x}^{2}+{\it a1}\,x+{\it a0}}}}\,{\rm d}
x+{\it \_C1} \right\} 
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]