# Problem with new MNRAS style files / newtx on arXiv

Tags: arxiv, newtx, newtxmath

### *Update: on [February 10th, 2017](https://arxiv.org/new#feb10_2017), the TeX processing system of arXiv has been updated to TeX Live 2016, so this should be no more an issue.*

I'm trying to submit a paper to the [arXiv](http://arxiv.org/) using the newest [MNRAS style files](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/mnras). The packages that creates a problem for me is:

```
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}
```

The first error I got is `` ! LaTeX Error: File `newtxtext.sty' not found `` and the same for `newtxmath.sty` so it seems arXiv do do have these packages(?). I tried to add the two style files together with the submission (Do I need to add other files to make this package work?) and this time it failed with error:

```
.! LaTeX Error: This NFSS system isn't set up properly.
```

If I comment out `\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}` everything works perfectly, but the style will not be the same as it is with this package.

Have anybody else experienced this and know why this happens? Is there a simple fix for this?

Please let me know if I need to add more details.

---

Added:  The other packages I use are:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,fleqn,usenatbib]{mnras}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{aecompl}
\usepackage{graphicx,color,bm}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{epsfig}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{wasysym}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\usepackage{enumitem}
```

Comment: Try the "old" packages `\usepackage{times,txfonts}`.  It's not the same you want, but at least should work with the old TeX distribution arXiv uses.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I tried it and adding **txfonts** fails with **! LaTeX Error: Too many math alphabets used in version normal.**.

Comment: Ok, then you should add more information about your preamble.

Comment: @giordano I have done this now. Anyway, your suggestion fixed the important problem I had that my tables became larger than the pagesize. This was fixed by adding the **times** package it seems so thanks for that.

Comment: First of all, make sure you are loading only packages you actually use (e.g., `latexsym` is useless if you load `amssymb`, as in your case; are you really using symbols from `wasysym` package?), then take look at [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/219310/31416) since you load `bm` (are you really using it?)

Comment: @giordano Thanks for all the tips. Unfortunately, it seems the problem remains even if I remove all these packages. I think I will just e-mail arXiv and ask directly. Hopefully they will know what to do. Otherwise the **times** package you suggested above seems to be an acceptable option.

Comment: I know at least one paper on arXiv which loads the `times` package, so I don't thinks this is the culprit.  The problem for the "too many math alphabets" problem is always that too many packages defining math alphabets are loaded. A single package cannot exceed alone the limit of math alphabets, it would be completely bugged.

Comment: @giordano That is what I said: **times** does works (apposed to **newtx**) so it can be used as an alternative as you suggested (you should add it as an answer). I made a final try using the MNRAS template, which only has a minimal amount of packages, and the problem is there also in this case (with the original NFSS error).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The packages `newtxtext` and `newtxmath` are a replacement for the old package `txfonts` (and `times`).  As of June 2015, arXiv [is running](http://arxiv.org/help/faq/texlive) TeX Live 2011, and the packages `newtxtext` and `newtxmath` weren't included in it.

If you still want to use Times-like fonts, the simplest solution is to replace those packages with the package they superseded, i.e. use

```
\usepackage{txfonts}
```

in place of

```
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}
```

Answer (score 2):

In 2023, I still ran into the problem. I attempted [the approach](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/251405/problem-with-new-mnras-style-files-newtx-on-arxiv/251482#251482) by @giordano. However, I found that the page layout changed. What worked for me was to upload my local copy of `newtx.sty` along with the tex file. With this approach, the page breaks and number of pages were the same between my local copy and the arXiv-generated version.