# mnras bibliography style - all citations showing up as question marks

Tags: bibliographies

This has been an ongoing problem, and it appears to be possibly an `mnras` problem, primarily.  I see others have had the same difficulties, but never with a sufficient resolution, so if anyone has tips or a full resolution, it would be greatly appreciated.  Here is a sample of my .tex:

```
\documentclass[fleqn,usenatbib]{mnras}
% Latex packages
%\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}   % Including figure files
\usepackage{amsmath}    % Advanced maths commands
\usepackage{amssymb}    % Extra maths symbols
\usepackage{wasysym}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{ae,aecompl} 
...
\bibliographystyle{mnras} 
\bibliography{paper}
```

And a sample of my .bib:

```
@ARTICLE{Field1965,
   author = {{Field}, G.~B.},
    title = "{Thermal Instability.}",
  journal = {\apj},
     year = 1965,
    month = aug,
   volume = 142,
    pages = {531},
      doi = {10.1086/148317},
   adsurl = {http://adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/1965ApJ...142..531F},
  adsnote = {Provided by the SAO/NASA Astrophysics Data System} 
}
```

I have attempted to compile in both ShareLatex (online) and Windows MikTeX with (pdfLaTeX+MakeIndex+BibTeX).  I have attempted to delete the temp aux and bbl files and start fresh, to no avail.  IF I change everything to APJ style, all citations show up normally.  I also attempted to add `\usepackage{natbib}` (although it should not be needed, given the option call to the `mnras` class), but nothing.  I have the most current versions of mnras.bst and mnras.cls to my knowledge.

I am hoping someone can help me figure out how to get my citations to appear, even if I have to use a different LaTeX editor.  It is challenging to check my work without being able to review the paper as it will appear in the journal.

Here is a sample error message from Sharelatex:

> Package natbib Warning: Citation `H01' on page 1 undefined on input line 77.

Comment: Did you run the normal cycle: `pdflatex -> bibtex -> pdflatex (twice)`? B.t.w., the `ae` and `aecompl` are obsolete and should not be used (cf. `l2tabu`).

Comment: It's hard to tell from your example what may be going on: Your sample bib entry uses the key `Field1965`, but the warning message you provide says something about an entry with key `H01` not being found. Is there an entry in the bib file that has the key `H01`? Your sample code doesn't seem to load the `natbib` package, yet the warning message you've posted indicates that you are, in fact, using `natbib`. Please provide a more focused query.

Comment: In regards to ae and aecompl - they are recommended by the mnras style guide.  But I can try removing them.
The cycle pdflatex -> bibtex -> pdflatex usually does not apply to Windows MikTeX or ShareLaTeX (indeed, it's not even possible in sharelatex).  I have attempted to run the MikTeX TexWorks circle (pdfLaTeX+MakeIndex+BibTeX) more than once however, to no avail.  

I apologize for the inconsistency in references, but all 108 references yield the same error message.  Yes, there is an entry for H01, which starts as:
    @article{H01,

Comment: To Mico - as I stated in the original query - natbib should be loaded as an option by the mnras class (see the \documentclass statement), however I have tried to load it independently, with no change in results.

Comment: Something that I forgot to mention above - the Figure references in the text also appear as question marks, though they are numbered properly.  Again this problem is eliminated if I switch to apj documentclass.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the input everyone.  It looks like this has been solved with an alternative solution, posted here:  [Problem with new MNRAS style files / newtx on arXiv](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/251405/problem-with-new-mnras-style-files-newtx-on-arxiv)

The details - replace

```
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}
```

with

```
\usepackage{txfonts}
```

When I remove the `newtxtext` and `newtxmath` packages, my references show up again!